# unable to change point size for na.values in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the point size for NA values.

```
        ggplot(dataframe, aes(col1, col2)) + 
geom_text(aes(label=col4),size=0.5, hjust=0, vjust=0) +
geom_point(aes(color = col3), size=1)
```

[This is what I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Cba.jpg)

I need the grey colors (NA) to display smaller and in white color.

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question.  Note you will need to map a variable to `size` in order to use `scale_size_manual`.  That means moving `size` inside `aes`.  Once you do that, take a look at the documentation for `scale_size_manual` for examples on how to use it.

Comment: I am trying to subsample my dataframe to give an appropriate reproducible example. But while I can run a plot with the full data I cannot with the subset.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this, the simplest might be to call `geom_point` twice, subsetting based on that column value.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(12341234)
dataframe <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(10, mean = 2, sd = 3),
                        col2 = rnorm(10, mean = 4, sd = 2),
                        col3 = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), NA, NA))

ggplot(dataframe[!is.na(dataframe$col3),], 
       aes(x = col1, 
           y = col2)) +  
  geom_point(aes(color = col3), 
             size = 4) + 
  geom_point(data = dataframe[is.na(dataframe$col3),], 
             color = "blue", 
             size = 8) + 
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("A", "B"), 
                     values = c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

Note this will mess up the legend (if you need one).

Another option is to replace NA values with something like "NA".

Comment: Thanks, but nor working for my dataset. I get an error: Error in `[.default`(dataframe$col3,  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Without a representative dataset where my answer doesn't work, it's going to be hard to troubleshoot.